# HTTP handlers exercise (tour of go)

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, http, go, server

The challenge, from [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/methods/14), "Exercise: HTTP Handlers":

> Implement the following types and define ServeHTTP methods on them. Register them to handle specific paths in your web server.

```
type String string

type Struct struct {
    Greeting string
    Punct    string
    Who      string
}
```

For example, you should be able to register handlers using:

```
http.Handle("/string", String("I'm a frayed knot."))
http.Handle("/struct", &Struct{"Hello", ":", "Gophers!"})
```

Solution:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
)

type String string

type Struct struct {
    Greeting    string
    Punct       string
    Who         string
}

func (s String) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, s); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error in ServerHTTP of String.")
    }
}

func (s *Struct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, s.Greeting, s.Punct, s.Who); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error in ServerHTTP of String.")
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/string", String("I'm a frayed knot."))
    http.Handle("/struct", &Struct{"Hello", ":", "Gophers!"})
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4000", nil))
}
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Answer (score 2):

The logic of trying to write or else `log.Fatal` is duplicated in the two `ServeHTTP` implementations. And the log message looks copy pasted, because it's the same for both the `String` and `*Struct` versions, for example:

> ```
> func (s *Struct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
>     if _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, s.Greeting, s.Punct, s.Who); err != nil {
>         log.Fatal("Error in ServerHTTP of String.")
>     }
> }
> ```

You could extract the common logic to a function, for example:

```
func writeOrElseLogFatal(writer func() (int, error), msg string) {
    if _, err := writer(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error in ServeHTTP of %s", msg)
    }
}
```

And then call it like this, for example for `*Struct`:

```
func (s *Struct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    writer := func() (int, error) {
        return fmt.Fprint(w, s.Greeting, s.Punct, s.Who)
    }
    writeOrElseLogFatal(writer, "Struct")
}
```

Or you could make things simpler by not logging at all in these functions:

```
func (s String) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, s)
}

func (s *Struct) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, s.Greeting, s.Punct, s.Who)
}
```